# When using ssh -X to connect to remote Ubuntu 18.04, couldn't it show server's local terminal GUI on my own PC?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04, remote-server

I found a strange thing when using `ssh -X` to connect to two servers.
Ubuntu16.04 is installed on one server, while Ubuntu 18.04 is installed on the other. I upload a simple shell script as following to both servers:

```html
#!/bin/bash

tab=" --tab"
options=()

cmds[1]="echo Banana"

cmds[2]="echo Cat"


for i in 1 2; do
options+=($tab -e "bash -c '${cmds[i]} ; bash'" )
done

gnome-terminal "${options[@]}"
exit 0
```

You know this script will open a new terminal window on server with two tabs. One tab will print "Banana", and the other tab will print "Cat".

Then I using `ssh -X` to  remotely login into the first server (Ubuntu 16.04) and execute this script on server, I got a new terminal opened with two tabs on my pc. That is I saw the remote terminal GUI of server on my own computer. However, if I repeated these steps on the second server(Ubuntu18.04), I will got nothing to show on my computer.

The I execute command`gedit` on the ssh login terminal when using `ssh -X` to login into both servers, I could see the GUI on my computer for both the cases.

I guess Ubuntu 18.04 cannot transport terminal's GUI through `ssh -X` to my pc. I was very confused about this. Could you please to explain the reason? And BTW, how can I see terminal's GUI of server in this case? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`ssh -X` doesn't transport a terminal. It *tunnels* a X11 connection.

X11 in its core is a network based display protocol. The programs (X clients) connect to a X server (a program running on your *local* machine) and instruct it to create windows and draw stuff to it. ***There is no graphical rendition of any kind anywhere else than the X server!***

`ssh -X` does not operate like Windows Remote Desktop, where there is an actual graphics environment running on the remote machine. Hence if you create two separate `ssh -X` connections (maybe even from different machines), these connections are completely independent from each other. *Hence you **cannot** use `ssh -X` to connect with a preexisting X session!*

What you want is either *Xvnc* or *Xpra*, where the graphics environment is actually run on the remote machine, and only the output is transferred to your local machine.

Comment: Thanks. I just wonder why I can see ubuntu16.04's server terminal GUI on my local pc?  This is quite strange since `ssh -X` doesn't transport a terminal.

Comment: @Gemini: SSH creates a connection to the server. Over this connection it creates a tunnel for X11 connections between Xorg on your local machine, and the remote machine. When you run gnome-terminal, it connects through this X11-through-SSH tunnel to the Xorg on your local machine and creates windows, and reacts to input events, just as if it were running on your local machine. I strongly suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System#Software_architecture – especially the X11 terminology for "client" and "server" may seem odd at first, but makes perfect sense.